# python, change the unit size in plot

Tags: python, plot

.I've plotting several plots in one figure. I attached it. as you can see the x-direction in the right side plots are messy and overwritten.
would anyone please tell me how can I increase the x unit to avoid this Problem or some other suggestion.

this is my code for the right side plots:

```
nx,ny= 9000, 16000

xmin = -30.0e-6       # nm resolution
xmax =  60.0e-6   

ymin = -80.0e-6     # nm resolution 
ymax = 80.0e-6 

X =np.linspace(xmin,xmax,nx)   #Generate linearly spaced vector. The spacing between the points is (x2-x1)/(n-1).
Y =np.linspace(ymin,ymax,ny)

plt.subplot(333)
fig1=plt.imshow(T_electron,  extent=[X.min()*1e6, X.max()*1e6, Y.min()*1e6, Y.max()*1e6], vmin=0, vmax=T_ele_mean, cmap='brg', aspect='auto')
plt.title('sdf '+ str(n)+ '; Time= ' +str(n*100)+ 'fs',color='Blue', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('$')
plt.ylabel('Tem_electron')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(333)
fig1=plt.imshow(T_proton,  extent=[X.min()*1e6, X.max()*1e6, Y.min()*1e6, Y.max()*1e6], vmin=0, vmax=T_ele_mean, cmap='brg', aspect='auto')
plt.title('sdf '+ str(n)+ '; Time= ' +str(n*100)+ 'fs',color='Blue', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('$')
plt.ylabel('Tem_proton')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(333)
fig1=plt.imshow(T_carbon,  extent=[X.min()*1e6, X.max()*1e6, Y.min()*1e6, Y.max()*1e6], vmin=0, vmax=T_ele_mean, cmap='brg', aspect='auto')
plt.title('sdf '+ str(n)+ '; Time= ' +str(n*100)+ 'fs',color='Blue', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('$')
plt.ylabel('Tem_carbon')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use  set_xlim() and set your prefered range

Comment: no. i want to Keep X=(-30, 60) but instead of 10 unit, i.e. -30,3--20,-10 ..I want to have 30,0, 30, 60. something like that. so I want to Change the unit distance

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can limit the number of ticks on the x or y axis. For your case, you could, for the x axis do:

```
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nticks=4)
```

Of course, you can change the nticks to be a convenient number by trial and error.